# Может ли Telegram-бот отправлять комментарии к постам в каналах?

Tags: telegram-bot, api, telegram

Есть Telegram-бот, который отправляет в канал некую информацию.
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы этот же бот периодически оставлял комментарии к тем постам, которые он создал.

Пример:

```
[19:00] Бот: -Пост-

    Комментарии (Discussions):
    [19:03] Бот: Комментарий к этому посту
    [19:18] Бот: Еще один комментарий к этому посту
```

Я пытался отправлять ботом комментарии к сообщению через `reply` в группе дискуссии, связанной с каналом, но не понимаю как сопоставлять `ID` сообщения в канале и `ID` сообщения в чате-дискуссии. Это работает, но бот отвечает не на тот пост, который требуется.

Как лучше это реализовать? Если ли встроенные методы в Telegram Bot API?

Comment: покажите пример кода

Comment: вы нашли способ получить id сообщения в чате?

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось так:
Сообщение в канал отправляется через `sendMessage?chat_id=[ИД_канала]&text=[текст сообщения]`. В полученном ответе есть ИД_Сообщения. Чтобы была возможность оставлять комментарии, к каналу должна быть привязана группа (причем супергруппа!), у нее есть свой [ИД_группы], отличный от [ИД_канала].
Комментарий к сообщению отправляется через `sendMessage?chat_id=[ИД_группы]_[ИД_Сообщения]&text=[текст комментария]&reply_to_message_id=[ИД_Сообщения]`
Ну и бот должен быть админом и в канале и в группе..